# why I can't set a custom template for street field in checkout shipping step via checkout_index_index.xml

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, xml

Could you explain me please why I can't set custom template for 'Street' fields group via checkout_index_index.xml. My code below:

```
<item name="street" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/form/element/checkout-input</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/form/element/checkout-input</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

But with the help of LayoutProcessor it's working fine...

```
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.street',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 0,
            'type' => 'group',
            'additionalClasses' => 'street',
            'children' => [
                [
                    'label' => __('* Address Line 1'),
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'Magento_Ui/form/element/checkout-input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '0',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => __('* Address Line 1'),
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'Magento_Ui/form/element/checkout-input'
                    ],
                    'dataScope' => '1',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'validation' => ['required-entry' => false, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 1, "max_text_length" => 255],
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely there is a module that is editing this already vis PHP. My understanding is PHP will override the XML.

Comment: I have the same thoughts,thanks